# TOC generated from addcontentsline has no spacing and no line breaks

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I am assembling a PDF from existing rendered PDFs, and I want to prefix that by a table of contents with PDF clickable links. Using `addcontentsline`, all the entries are crammed together in one line, there are no line breaks between the entries of the TOC, nor any space between the entry title and the page number:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
% get rid of the horrible coloured boxes around links
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage[UKenglish,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Motivationsschreiben}
\includepdf[pages=-]{application-letter.pdf}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae}
\includepdf[pages=-]{cv.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: article has no chapter, use section instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer uh, that was quick, thanks! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

article.cls has no chapters, so you need `section` as type:

```
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Motivationsschreiben}
```